# vroom incorrectly parsing columns with space delim

Tags: r

I'm trying to read some space-delimited data using vroom. About a year ago this worked fine giving 11 columns of numeric data:

```
library(vroom)
fname <- "http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/auto/Global/Complete_TAVG_complete.txt"
dat <- vroom(file = fname, delim = " ", col_names = FALSE, comment = "%", na = "NaN")
```

Now I get 58 columns in `dat` mostly of empty logicals. Is this an encoding issue with the white space?

Here is the `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vroom_1.6.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like a fixed width file to me, so a delimiter won't work. Use `vroom::vroom_fwf()`.

```
url = "http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/auto/Global/Complete_TAVG_complete.txt"
f = tempfile()
download.file(url, f)
on.exit(unlink(f))
dat = vroom::vroom_fwf(f, skip = 35)
```